# Disable notifications per app and time frame

Tags: notifications, automation

I would like to know if there's any app or any Tasker plugin that would allow me to block notifications on the weekends.

I got two email accounts, one personal with the Gmail app and the other work-related with the Inbox app. I receive like eighty emails on the last one per day (even on weekends), I would like to automatically block the Inbox app notifications from Friday night to Monday morning. Right now I do this by hand every weekend (and sometimes I forget to enable them again on Monday).

I found plenty of answers on how to block notifications per app, but not per time frame.

(If it matters, the phone is a non-rooted Samsung Galaxy S6)

Comment: In Lollipop, you can't block notifications without root access, adb, or through Settings app. For rooted Android, [Notifications Off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.NotificationsOff) would easily work. If not, appops command can be used.

Comment: In the Samsung s6 with lollipop sure you can. Just long press the notification, press info and then change block notifications to on.

Comment: As I said, *you can't block notifications without root access, adb,* ***or through Settings app***. That long press opens the app's page through Settings app!

Comment: Anyway, please read the question, i don't need that, i need to block it by time frame.

Comment: I understand the question well. Time frame is just a trigger, a context here. It cannot do anything on its own. There is no point in arguing over a trigger since you can't achieve what you want without *root access, adb, or through Settings app*

Comment: Please, add your explanation as an answer and I'll mark it off there's no other valid answer in a couple of days.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Settings open Notifications (under Device heading) ➡ Do not disturb ➡ Automatic rules ➡ + Add rule ➡ Type [Rule name], select [Time rule] or [Event rule], select OK ➡ select options for the new rule: Days, Filter notifications. Start time, End time, Do not disturb type.

Comment: The setting is found in different locations depending on the phone manufacturer and is sometimes not available depending on the model of phone.

Comment: My Filter notifications screen is loaded with notifications I've blocked in the past. It's a nonsensical, unordered list with specific notifications that have the full app name "com.organisation.whatsapp" etc. I think this is from a time when this screen functioned differently. Or maybe I used it incorrectly in the first place. Is there a way to clear all of them again and start over?

Comment: Hm, it seems I do not have the "Filter notifications" option for a rule on a FP2 running a nearly stock Android 6. Anyone know if this screen was introduced in a later Android version?

Comment: I can't see any 'filter notifications' running Android 8 (Android One version). Can anyone confirm that it still exists?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done quite easily via [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) but requires root.

1. Create a profile using the 'Day' and 'Time' triggers
2. Create a task which turns off notifications for XXX app via [Secure Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin)
   (Create Task, go to Plugin, Secure Settings, Root actions, Package notifications, select app, toggle)
3. Set the profile to trigger the task.

Comment: I have rooted phone (Nexus 5X), did exacly what it says and I'm still getting notifications. Any idea why?

Comment: I prefer the method SoccerPhreak has posted, it does not require root and has enough options for me to be happy I will get notified of the things I need to know about and for the less important things I can safely ignore them.

Comment: This option seems to work fine for me. It might be interesting to note that this controls the normal Android "Block notifications" option (which can be reached through (on Android 6) Settings -> Sound & Notification -> App Notificiations, or by longpressing a notification and pressing the info icon). AFAICS this means that all notifications from that app are suppressed (not just the sound, which is what I was hoping for originally).

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same problem for quite some time. I have just developed an app that allows you to cancel notifications from specific applications on the day and time you want. Also, you can set a notification title and/or content, so only notifications of selected app with that title or content will be cancelled.

For example, you could cancel WhatsApp/Telegram notifications from chat group called "Work", between 7pm and 10am during weekdays, and whole weekends.

Here is the app: [Disconnect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.edukunapps.schedulenotification)

Answer (score 1):

I use [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) to put my phone in Do not Disturb (DnD) mode based on date and time. Then set exclusions from DnD on the apps I want to get notifications on during that time frame. It will suppress all notifications based on time but let through the excluded apps.

Comment: Which IFTTT applet do you use to control 'do not disturb'?

Answer (score 0):

I use this app called Notification Blocker from the Play Store, it is perfect. The only thing is it will only allow you to block during a specified time frame and not by days of the week. You could always try and set up two rules though, one for the weekday and one for the weekends.