# Method to block calls on dual SIM and block notifications from some apps (scheduled)

Tags: tasker, dual-sim, do-not-disturb, motorola-moto-g5

I recently got a Motorola G5S Smartphone with Android 7.1.1 with Dual SIM. One SIM is work-related, the other private. Also, every App on my phone is either work-related or private.

I'm searching for an app (or integrated function) which can do the following:

- block all calls & messages coming into the work-SIM at night & on weekends
- block notifications of the work-related apps at night & on weekends

The tricky thing here is that I do want to use the mobile data from the work-SIM, so disabling it completely is not an option.

I checked out [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) but the description doesn't say anything about blocking calls coming in to one of the numbers/SIMs. On the other hand, the "Do not disturb"-option also cannot to block only calls to one SIM ([at least on my phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/137606/how-to-disable-notifications-per-app-and-time-frame)).

Is there any other app or even built-in feature that I'm missing? Rooting the device would not be a problem, I guess.

Comment: @beeshyams That might be OK for an "internal" work number, but if the number of the work SIM is published, it might be getting called by people not in the contacts list at all.

Comment: Right, but the point is that an unknown contact might be a work or a personal call. Maybe the questioner is happy to treat unknown contacts as always one or the other; it would be helpful if they could come back and clarify.

Comment: An ideal solution would be to block or allow calls depending on the number/SIM. But I think, a block depending on the group (I have a private and a work address book) plus blocking unknown contacts would also be fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Caveats**

- OP is willing to reject unknown numbers in weekends
- They have their office contacts and private labeled in their address book
- Only office people call on office SIM , they are not aware of private SIM number and vice versa for private contacts
- They can continue to use data from Office SIM
- Not tested on dual SIM but should work

I don't think it is possible using SIM based approach, alternative *non root* [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) approach using [macrodroid](/questions/tagged/macrodroid) which is simple and easy free up to five macros ( [App link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid&hl=en) )

## Blocking calls in off times

Create a macro and name, save it  (Add Triggers,  actions and constraints by pressing **+**)

**Triggers**

1. Call Incoming → Select Groups →  Office (office numbers stored in contacts and grouped by this name)
2. Call Incoming → Select Contacts → Non Contact (additionally select Unknown caller if required)

**Actions**

Call Reject

**Constraints**

Day of the week → Saturday & Sunday

add constraint of  AND /OR /XOR/ NOT → OR (ensure the little inverted triangle shows OR)

add constraint Time of day → set start and end time for example 2000 to 0800

what it does is that on weekends OR during specified times calls made by non contacts  / unknown numbers and office folks are rejected

Test it by changing triggers and constraints . Use the 3 buttons menu → Test Macro

[image]

## Blocking Office app notifications

**Trigger**

Notification → Notification Received → select apps → choose office apps from drop down → Text content → Any

**Actions**

1. Volume change → Notification → Set slider to zero
2. Clear Notifications → select apps → choose office apps from drop down → Text content → Any
3. Volume change → Notification → Set slider to the level desired

**Constraints** As in above macro ( Hint: from 3 dot menu use clone macro to get a copy of macro to save repetitive selection)

What it does

- Action 1 mutes the notification volume to zero ( you don't need to hear the *ding* when you don't want to be notified)
- Clear notifications during the time / day chosen in constraints
- Action 3 restores desired volume level so that you can hear other other notifications that you  *want to*

[image]

Comment: For testing: Long press on triggers for instance and disable it . add a trigger that is convenient like a friends phone . Once the testing is done long press to enable.

Comment: Haven't tested fully ,so let me know if there any issues

Comment: Reading your comment under question again, this macro can be modified to choose numbers instead of groups. Selecting numbers from a large list of contacts in the drop down is painful. I know how bad it was to select a dozen contacts, and created a group to facilitate this for myself. If that works better for you, you can go do that