# How to enable Do Not Disturb for 1 SIM only in a Dual SIM phone?

Tags: root-access, lineageos, dual-sim, oneplus-two, do-not-disturb

I have a rooted OnePlus 2 running LineageOS 14 latest.

How can I enable the Do Not Disturb feature for just my personal SIM card, without also enabling it for my work SIM card? Specifically, I'd like to be able to have my personal SIM on Priority mode, if possible, which allows starred/favourited contacts to still ring.

I plan to upgrade to LineageOS 15 soon, but I can do this right away if it is a prerequisite.

Comment: Related [Method to block calls on dual SIM and block notifications from some apps (scheduled)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/191882/131553)

Answer (score 0):

Method one
Disbable the notification tone and the ringtone for the simcard that you do not want to use. Just go yo sounds and set it to none for sim 1 or two.

Method 2:
This is a tricky one since there is no default method that i can find to do this, but if you have used tasker before and your phone is rooted then there should be a plugin or a method to do this.

[Tasker on Playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en)

Goodluck mate