# Notify me only once or twice a day

Tags: notifications, notification-bar, push-notifications

Is there a way to bundle all my android notifications and let notifications arrive at a specific time of the day? For example, let's say I only want to check notifications at 10am and 6pm, everyday. All notifications after 10am until 6pm are put on halt, and at 6pm, I get a single prompt to view all the notifications from various apps.

My phone runs on Android 6, with MIUI 9 on top of it and I know for sure that this is not supported. Is there any android version or device in which such a feature is supported?

Comment: A very similar question: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/137606/how-to-disable-notifications-per-app-and-time-frame