# Android 8: enable and disable notification for certain apps during certain hours

Tags: 8.0-oreo

I only found answers to this question for older versions of Android and they did not work for me: how do I enable and disable notification of certain apps (Outlook for example) during certain hours automatically WITHOUT using an additional app? The context is that I use my phone for both private and professional emails and I would prefer not to be bothered by work emails outside of my working hours.

On older versions of android I was able to set a schedule (like this: [How to disable notifications per app and time frame?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/137606/how-to-disable-notifications-per-app-and-time-frame)), but now I do not find how any more. Am I just being stupid or was the notification subsystem changed?

I have a Samsung Galaxy S7 on Android 8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable notifications per app and time frame?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/137606/how-to-disable-notifications-per-app-and-time-frame)

Comment: @Firelord This question is specific to Android 8. The answer in your link does not work any more as stated in my question.

Comment: Refer here @njg https://www.androidcentral.com/how-adjust-do-not-disturb-settings-android-o

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem for quite some time. I have just developed an app that allows you to cancel notifications from specific applications on the day and time you want. Also, you can set a notification title and/or content, so only notifications of selected app with that title or content will be cancelled.

For example, you could cancel WhatsApp/Telegram notifications from chat group called "Work", between 7pm and 10am during weekdays, and whole weekends.

Here is the app: [Disconnect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.edukunapps.schedulenotification)